# WCF Service, the type provided as the service attribute values…could not be found, but it was working earlier

Tags: c#, wcf

Sorry for my english btw. I have trouble with adding service reference. It returns error:

```
The type 'WcfService1.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
```

I tried solutions from this topic: [WCF Service, the type provided as the service attribute values…could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591972/wcf-service-the-type-provided-as-the-service-attribute-values-could-not-be-foun)

When I was trying to add service reference on my test project it worked properly, but then i tried to implement it into my main project and it returned this error. Next again i tried to add service reference in my test project but now it also doesn't work. This test project is completely clear. This is my Service1 markup.

```cs
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService1.Service1" %>
```

I would understand everything but i don't know why it worked earlier on clean project, but now it doesn't work.

Comment: So you have a class that is in the namespace WcfService1 and is called Service1? In other words: `namespace WcfService1 { public class Service1 { <code here> } }` and it compiles without errors?

Comment: Exactly, it compiles without errors.